# Long click listener is not work in WebView. how to enable listener

Tags: android, android-webview

I try to use long click functionality in my **`WebView`** but no any action is performed
I try a lot by using

```
private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view) {
// code
}
```

and this **`setonlongclicklistener()`** etc but no any good solution

Here my 2 questions

**Is any way to show defualt contextmenu for `WebView` copytext, saveimage, openlink,... etc**
or

**how to implement dialog for our own WebView like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Override onTouch method of your webview and return true for ACTION_DOWN events. Thereby you consume your down event.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  switch (event.getAction()) { 
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
        return true;
  }
  }
```

Hope it helps.